# Is there a change in the processing of the order of events in iOS 8.1 and xCode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a simple application which has several UITextField objects on them. On the Editing Did End event, I call first responder save() so that the data is persisted using core data.

This has worked without issues since my initial release of the application.  I am currently adding a new feature to my app, and noticed a behavior difference which I am unable to resolve.

I have a UIButton which is linked to the Touch Up Inside event which triggers a method to send an email which compiles all the data that has been persisted.

However the order of these events is not consistent between my current binary and the new one.

With my existing app in the App Store, if I am editing a UITextField and click to the Email Button, the events fire in the order of Editing Did End -> save() THEN Touch Up Inside -> sendEmail().

With my beta binary running, performing the same steps has the events fire in the reverse order: Touch Up Inside -> sendEmail() THEN Editing Did End -> save()

This causes issues since my latest values haven't persisted yet and they aren't included in the email.

Have these events been reordered?  Is there something that I need to change in my application to allow for these?  I can work around it by using editing did start, set a flag to state it's dirty and then call save before generating the email, but that seems more like a hack than a solution.

So I thought I'd ask.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just have touch up inside call `save()` and then `sendEmail()`?

Comment: I tried that - but they still seemed to fire out of order.  I will try that again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ever assume that the order of internal Apple events in the runloop will be in order, especially when they are related to independent objects.

In this case you have the UITextField delegate method firing, and the UIButton touch. Don't link the two in your code. If you need the data to be saved before the email is sent, please make sure that the data is indeed saved before the email is sent.

One way to do it is to have a bool like `dataIsModified` that you set to true whenever any data is modified, and reset when the save is done. Then in the email sending method, check if dataIsModified, then save again.

Comment: That's where I was going with this, but I didn't know if was needed.